# Where can I find the API KEY for Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to figure out how the new version of GCM or Firebase Cloud Messaging works so I moved one of my projects to the new Firebase console, If I did not have the API KEY or I want to create a new one... where can I do it?

Comment: You need API key only for the officially not supported languages. https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/

Answer (score 369, accepted):

It's in https://console.firebase.google.com/project/(your-project-id)/settings/cloudmessaging

You can find the API KEY in:

`(gear-next-to-project-name) > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging`

Server Key is the API key.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering what happen if the API KEY get compromised, how to reset it or create a new one..

Comment: ps: a workaround to rotate the key consist in opening the firebase project from http://cloud.google.com > API manager > credentials

Comment: Is the **Server key** same as the API key ?

Comment: In this context yes

Comment: I think the Server Key is not the same as the Web API Key, some other answers in here show they are used for different pourposes.

Comment: how can you say server key is main API key?

Answer (score 75):

**STEP 1:** Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)

**STEP 2:** Select your Project

**STEP 3:** Click on Settings icon and select **Project Settings**

[image: Select Project Setting]

**STEP 4:** Select **CLOUD MESSAGING** tab

[image]

Comment: visualization is better than text!

Answer (score 12):

**Enter here:**

[https: //console.firebase.google.com/project/**your-project-name**/overview](http://https:%20//console.firebase.google.com/project/your-project-name/overview)

(replace `your-project` with your `project-name`)
 and click in "**Add firebase in your web app**"(the red circle icon) this action show you a dialog with:

- apiKey
- authDomain
- databaseURL
- storageBucket
- messagingSenderId

Comment: here is example with screen shot : https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-can-i-get-api-key-auth-domain-database-url-and-storage-bucket-from-my-firebase-account

Answer (score 11):

You can open the project in the firebase, then you should click on the project overview, then goto project settings you will see the **web API Key** there.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are two primary ways to locate your Firebase API key:

**Check the Project Settings:**

- Navigate to the Project Settings section of your Firebase console.
- Click on the General tab.
- Look for the Web API Key field. Your APIkey should be displayed there, starting
  with "ALZa***********
  [image]

**Access from Service Accounts:**

- If the API key isn't visible in the General tab, proceed to the Service Accounts
  section within Project Settings.
  [image]
- Under the All service accounts section, you will see number of service accounts
  click on that.
  [image]
- A new page of the IAM & Admin will appeared.
- click on search bar and type the API key.
  [image]
- Click on the Credentials option.
  [image]
- Select Show key to reveal your API key.
  [image]

Key Points:

The API key is crucial for interacting with Firebase services from your application.
Treat your API key with confidentiality, as it grants access to your Firebase project.
If you encounter any difficulties locating your API key, refer to the official Firebase documentation for detailed guidance.

Comment: Thank you so much for this extensive explanation. it was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

1.Create a Firebase project in the Firebase console, if you don't already have one. If you already have an existing Google project associated with your app, click Import Google Project. Otherwise, click Create New Project.

2.Click settings and select Permissions.

3.Select Service accounts from the menu on the left.

4.Click Create service account.

- Enter a name for your service account.
- You can optionally customize the ID from the one automatically generated from the name.
- Select Furnish a new private key and leave the Key type as JSON.
- Leave Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation unselected.
- Click Create.

This might be what you're looking for. This was in the tutorial on the site

Comment: This for the officially supported firebase SDKs. Where in the doc it says, Java and nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

You can find API KEY from the google-services.json file

Answer (score 2):

Please add new api key from `Firebase -> Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Legacy Server Key` to the workspace file i.e `google-services.json`

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on Project Overview -> Project Settings,
2. Then click on Cloud Messaging,
3. Then click on three dots to the right side of Cloud Messaging Api(Legacy) and enable it,[click on, to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FarvR.png)

4. Come back to Project Overview -> Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging, here you will get the Server Key

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current api key programmatically in android studio, use

```
 FirebaseOptions.fromResource(context).getApiKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Project Overview -> Project Settings
2. Copy your web api key[image: Get you web api key]

Answer (score -1):

You can also get the API key in the android studio. Switch to Project view in android
then find the google-services.json. Scroll down and you will find the api_key

Answer (score -1):

Once you just go to autherization section it will generate and also make sure enable legacy if need
[Web api key is not generated in firebase while creating a new project as stated on the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64690983/web-api-key-is-not-generated-in-firebase-while-creating-a-new-project-as-stated)