# Can't enable the API for GCM in Google developer console

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have an account in Google Cloud Platform. I have many projects in that account. Now I created a new project and API and try to enable the API for GCM, but the page is redirecting to firebase cloud messaging documentation page. Before I created project and API, there was no problem. But now I can't enable API for GCM. Can any body help to find out the issue?

Comment: Have you tried searching for GCM in the search and Enabling it? Check [this picture](http://imgur.com/a/2r2KU).

Answer (score 0):

Google migrated GCM to FCM. So, In the Google API console when you click the Google cloud messaging service it will redirect the new Firebase console.

But, No worry there has still option to enable GCM without using FCM. When you create a project you can see a list of services enabled default by google. `If you can't see the list just refresh or logout and login again your project. You can see the enabled API services list for that project`

Answer (score 0):

API Key management for GCM has been moved to Firebase Console. You can create a new Firebase Project (or import an existing cloud project) and you should obtain a new Server Key for Cloud Messaging.

see the updated documentation:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#create-an-api-project
and the stack overflow question: [Where can I find the API KEY for Firebase Cloud Messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337512/where-can-i-find-the-api-key-for-firebase-cloud-messaging/)