# Problems with Google Developer Console - Sender ID for GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-developers-console

I'm not a developer, but a graphic that needs to publish a digital kiosk magazine made with twixl platform.

I followed the steps of the twixl documentation to create a Sender ID for notifications on Android (*FCM/GCM*). I created an app where I associated a Sender ID (API key) and everything worked. I also have the statistics for a few days in which the app was active.

For certificate problems, however, I had to cancel this publication and do another, from the same account (*app@pizzanew.it*).

In Google Cloud Platform, I deleted the old project and I created a new one. Now, when I go to the Google Developer Console to associate a new id, it tells me that the value of API Key is not valid.

It may be that it is linked to the old app or in some way that I do not know? But the old app is no longer published.

I do not know how to do it, but I must be able to set this id for notifications. I configured only general information of the new app, but it has not yet been published, and I have not uploaded the new APK. May it's because of it?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: So are you sure you change sender id in android manifest because is different

Comment: Something's bothering me in your post -- *I created an app where I associated a **Sender ID (API key)** and everything worked.* -- The Sender ID and API key (more commonly known as Server Key) are different. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm

Comment: I use a platform and I can't control manifest file.
I can only insert data in my console developer google play.

I deleted the first project and its api key, and ricreated another project and another api key. 
Both (the first project that I deleted, and the new) are refered to the same account.

Answer (score 1):

There are two concept to understand:

**sender-id** : this is the ID of the project in Google Cloud Console (for old projects) or Firebase Console (for new projects)

**server-key** : (also referred as API-Key) this is the "password" for your server to send messages.

**If you want to change your SENDER-ID:**

1. create a new Firebase Project: https://firebase.google.com
2. read the SenderId & Server-Key in the settings
   ([Where can I find the API KEY for Firebase Cloud Messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337512/where-can-i-find-the-api-key-for-firebase-cloud-messaging))
3. update the **sender-id** in all the configurations you have
   (if you are using the FCM sdk you need to download the new google-services.json file)

PS: you should be able to undelete the old project from Google Cloud Platform if you need to keep the same sender-id.
But new  projects should be created in Firebase Console, and old projects who need a new server-key should import the old project into the Firebase Console.

Comment: hello diego, thank you very much for your help.
Are you italian? Can I write in italian?
As I answeres to your colleagues, I use an already structured platform so I can not operate on the code file.
I can only put the sender id in the build publisher of platform and the api key in developer google console.

Comment: Now, because I created and deleted some projects to try to solve, I can not even more to set the type of credentials.
Is there a service number to call and ask to google assistance to do a check on my account, helping me to understand where is the problem?