# FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hope all of you aware of this class, used to get notification token whenever firebase notification token got refreshed we get the refreshed token from this class, From following method.

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
```

To use this as i want to implement FCM, I extended MyClass from `FirebaseInstanceIdService`

But, Showing that **FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated**

Does anybody know this?,
What method or class i should use instead of this to get refreshed token as this is deprecated.

I'm using : `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'`

I checked the document for same there is nothing mentioned about this. : [FCM SETUP DOCUMENT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService)

---

**UPDATE**

**This issue has been Fixed.**

As Google deprecated the `FirebaseInstanceService`,

I asked the question to find the way and i get to know that We can get the Token from **FirebaseMessagingService**,

As before, when i asked the Question Documents were not updated but Now Google docs updated so for more info, Refer this google doc : [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService)

**OLD From : FirebaseInstanceService  (Deprecated)**

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
```

**NEW From : FirebaseMessagingService**

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.d("NEW_TOKEN",s);
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/548)

Comment: Here also : https://medium.com/android-school/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated-50651f17a148

Comment: online documentation is just updated. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onNewToken(java.lang.String)

Comment: Is it necessary/correct to call `super.onNewToken(s);` ? (I don't see it being called on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client .)

Comment: would there be any change in manifest?

Comment: You just don't need to define FirebaseInstanceService in manifest as it is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for this. Android Studio needs to update the instructions in their Firebase setup wizard.

Comment: Old question. Please update.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Check the [reference documentation for `FirebaseInstanceIdService`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService):

> This class was deprecated.
>
> In favour of overriding `onNewToken` in `FirebaseMessagingService`. Once that has been implemented, this service can be safely removed.

Weirdly enough the JavaDoc for `FirebaseMessagingService` doesn't mention the `onNewToken` method yet. It looks like not all updated documentation has been published yet. I've filed an internal issue to get the updates to the reference docs published, and to get the samples in the guide updated too.

In the meantime both the old/deprecated calls, and the new ones should work. If you're having trouble with either, post the code and I'll have a look.

Comment: The [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) have also not been updated yet.

Comment: Yes @frank,  the method do exists, but related documents not updated yet.

Comment: @kev That sounds like a (valid) new question. Please create a new post, with a minimal complete code snippet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen already did. Have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296171/fcm-onnewtoken-vs-firebaseinstanceid/51296330#51296330

Comment: I found about this update for Xamarin Android too. Added OnNewToken method in class that extends FirebaseMessagingService. But that method is not hit. I cannot figure out what should i do. Is it different in Android Manifest file for xamarin.

Answer (score 184):

**Update 11-12-2020**

Now [**`FirebaseInstanceId`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getInstanceId()) is also deprectaed

Now we need to use `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
            if(it.isComplete){
                firebaseToken = it.result.toString()
                Util.printLog(firebaseToken)
            }
        }
```

[**Yes** **`FirebaseInstanceIdService`** is deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService)

> **FROM DOCS :-**  This class was deprecated.
> In favour of `overriding onNewToken` in `FirebaseMessagingService`. Once that has been implemented, this service can be safely removed.

No need to use `FirebaseInstanceIdService` service to get FCM token You can safely remove `FirebaseInstanceIdService` service

Now we need to **`@Override onNewToken`**  get `Token` in `FirebaseMessagingService`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
        Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());

        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilesh_channel";

        long pattern[] = {0, 1000, 500, 1000};

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Your Notifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(pattern);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        // to diaplay notification in DND Mode
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            channel.canBypassDnd();
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

#**EDIT**

> You need to register your **`FirebaseMessagingService`** in manifest file like this

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

#how to get token in your activity

> [**`.getToken();`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#getToken()) is also deprecated
> if you need to get token in your activity than Use [**`getInstanceId ()`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getInstanceId())

Now we need to use [**`getInstanceId ()`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getInstanceId()) to generate token

`getInstanceId ()` Returns the `ID` and automatically generated token for this `Firebase` project.

This generates an Instance ID if it does not exist yet, which starts periodically sending information to the Firebase backend.

**Returns**

- Task which you can use to see the result via the `InstanceIdResult` which holds the `ID` and `token`.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
           Log.e("newToken",newToken);

     }
 });
```

##EDIT 2

Here is the working code for kotlin

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(p0: String?) {

    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {


        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilesh_channel"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Your Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)

            notificationChannel.description = "Description"
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
            notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000)
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        // to diaplay notification in DND Mode
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            channel.canBypassDnd()
        }

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage!!.getNotification()!!.getBody())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setAutoCancel(true)


        notificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build())

    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178504/discussion-on-answer-by-nilesh-rathod-firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated).

Comment: why is nobody showing how to import FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: hi, what i must use FirebaseInstallations  or  FirebaseMessaging ?

Comment: @Tony currently I'm using `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()`

Comment: this answer should be accepted answer to help others find the deprecated issue. many article still using FirebaseInstanceId to get new FCM token. Hopefully others read my comment

Comment: onNewToken method is removed

Answer (score 16):

Simply call this method to get the Firebase Messaging Token

```
public void getFirebaseMessagingToken ( ) {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance ().getToken ()
                .addOnCompleteListener ( task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful ()) {
                        //Could not get FirebaseMessagingToken
                        return;
                    }
                    if (null != task.getResult ()) {
                        //Got FirebaseMessagingToken
                        String firebaseMessagingToken = Objects.requireNonNull ( task.getResult () );
                        //Use firebaseMessagingToken further
                    }
                } );
    }
```

The above code works well after adding this dependency in build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
```

**Note:** This is the code modification done for the above dependency to resolve deprecation. (Working code as of 9th May 2021)

Comment: hi, what i must use FirebaseInstallations or FirebaseMessaging ?

Comment: Hi @Tony, For sending a cloud message through firebase, 'firebase-messaging' must be used. Looks like 'firebase-installations' is not providing the complete token which is required for sending a cloud message to other devices. Correct me if I am wrong. TIA!

Answer (score 14):

And this:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken()
```

suppose to be solution of deprecated:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

**EDIT**

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().getResult().getToken()`
can produce exception if the task is not yet completed, so the method witch Nilesh Rathod described (with `.addOnSuccessListener`) is correct way to do it.

Kotlin:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener(this) { instanceIdResult ->
        val newToken = instanceIdResult.token
        Log.e("newToken", newToken)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

`FirebaseinstanceIdService` is deprecated. 
So have to use "FirebaseMessagingService"

Sea the image please:

[image]

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin allows for even simpler code than what's shown in other answers.

To get the new token whenever it's refreshed:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
        Log.d("FMS_TOKEN", token)
    }
    ...
}
```

To get the token from anywhere at runtime:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.d("FMS_TOKEN", it.token)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**In KOTLIN:-** If you want to save **Token** into DB or shared preferences then override onNewToken in [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService)

```
override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
    }
```

Get token at run-time,use

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
                        .addOnSuccessListener(this@SplashActivity) { instanceIdResult ->
                            val mToken = instanceIdResult.token
                            println("printing  fcm token: $mToken")
                        }
```

Comment: Now it's `override fun onNewToken(token: String)` (without the question mark).

Answer (score 4):

FCM implementation Class:

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
if(data != null) {
 // Do something with Token
  }
}
}
// FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
  super.onNewToken(token);
  if (!token.isEmpty()) {
  Log.e("NEW_TOKEN",token);
 }
}
}
```

And call its initialize in Activity or APP :

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(
                instanceIdResult -> {
                    String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i("FireBaseToken", "onFailure : " + e.toString());
                    }
                });
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
  <service android:name="ir.hamplus.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**If you added "INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" don't forget to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use  `FirebaseMessagingService()`  instead of `FirebaseInstanceIdService`

Answer (score 2):

And here the solution for C#/Xamarin.Android:

```
var token = await FirebaseInstallations.Instance.GetToken(forceRefresh: false).AsAsync<InstallationTokenResult>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`getInstance().getInstanceId()` is also now deprecated and `FirebaseMessaging` is being used now.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val token = task.result
    } else {
        Timber.e(task.exception)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does forceRefresh do? refresh token when ever the activity is opened?

Comment: @AbhishekAN yes it will force it to get a new tokwn.

Comment: hi, what i must use FirebaseInstallations or FirebaseMessaging ?

Answer (score 1):

First import `import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;` 
then
Simply use `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().getResult();` instead of `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken().getresult()`

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use service

```
<service android:name=".utils.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
 </service>

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
           @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN = = == = = =",s);
    }

}
```

If you want to use in Activity

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance ().getToken ().addOnCompleteListener ( task -> {
                Log.e("spalsh",task.getResult());
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add This On build.gradle.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'

Answer (score 0):

Use FirebaseMessaging instead

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
          if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
            return;
          }

          // Get new FCM registration token
          String token = task.getResult();

          // Log and toast
          String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
          Log.d(TAG, msg);
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin I use the following

```
val fcmtoken = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.await()
```

and for the extension functions

```
public suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T {
    // fast path
    if (isComplete) {
        val e = exception
        return if (e == null) {
            if (isCanceled) {
                throw CancellationException("Task $this was cancelled normally.")
            } else {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                result as T
            }
        } else {
            throw e
        }
    }

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        addOnCompleteListener {
            val e = exception
            if (e == null) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                if (isCanceled) cont.cancel() else cont.resume(result as T)
            } else {
                cont.resumeWithException(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Task<T>.await()` is available from https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services so just add `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.2'` to your gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in your activity , this worked for me.

```
private void registerInBackground() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SplashActivity.this);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            String token = task.getResult();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From `com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2` , the way to do it is as such:

`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.result`

Since this is a Task, though, it doesn't return the value this way. You need to wait for it using a callback.

A nice way to solve it is via this:

```
@WorkerThread
fun <TResult> Task<TResult>.awaitForResult(): Task<TResult> {
    val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
    this.addOnCompleteListener {
        countDownLatch.countDown()
    }
    countDownLatch.await()
    return this
}

@WorkerThread
fun <TResult> Task<TResult>.awaitForResultOrNull(): Task<TResult>? {
    val task = awaitForResult()
    return if (task.isSuccessful)
        return task else null
}
```

So example usage:

```
val regId : String? = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.awaitForResultOrNull()?.result
```

Answer (score 0):

The new way

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(task -> Log.e(TAG, "Token: "+task.getResult()));
```