# Notification Services

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive Android notifications using firebase. I have defined the below services. But the service `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` is running on running the app for the first time. I don't even have a database for the user at that time. I want to store the firebase token for the user, but first I want to make an entry for the user on first activity and start the services on the second activity. SO that I can store the token of the user.

Android Manifest file

```
<service
    android:name="in.anamika.anamika.notifications.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name="in.anamika.anamika.notifications.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: You can save the token in sharedPreference until the DB is created and later store it in DB

Comment: are you using firebase database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on how I understood your question, I see more than 1 solution which are as follows:

1. Initially you can save Token to shared preference, as mentioned by Nainal 
   And later when the user successfully logs in and database created you can store to table.

The updated API returns **Task** on which you can add onSuccess listener and that will be called when you can successfully get token.

```
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(yourActivity,  
    new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {                    
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                      String deviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                      // Do whatever you want with your token now
                      // i.e. store it on SharedPreferences or DB
                      // or directly send it to server 
                }
});
```

2. It'd be quite long but You can send own custom broadcast from **onTokenRefresh()** or **onNewToken()**, Set callback interface in to Broadcast receiver from activity and get that call in Activity by overriding callback method.

Note: the **FirebaseInstanceIdService** is deprecated instead we can override onNewToken() to get new/updated token in FirebaseMessagingService only.
you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated) link.

Answer (score 3):

put this code in your launcher/main activity:

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Log.d("", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
```

this will get you the token, than go to this below web -

`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification` and `create new notification->choose single device->paste` the token that was logged in your android studio project->check if you got the notification

Comment: Starting from version "17.0.1" of the Cloud Messaging SDK, `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` has been deprecated in favor of `getInstanceId()`. It returns a `Task<InstanceIdResult>` that you can attach a listener to, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125384/5861618)

Comment: Actually, above solution doesn't solve my problem. If I get token every time on launcher activity and send the token to DB, that would be inefficient. Can I put some kind of listener in my launcher activity like onTokenRefresh() ? I want that just for the first time I can sent the token to DB from specific activity. And after that from service itself i.e OnTokenRefresh

Comment: IF the user not logged in initially. I cannot put his/her token in the database. So, if the user is not logged in, I want to wait til he login and after login I want a listener like onTokenRefresh.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Solution is based on `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and FirebaseMessagingService classes. But it will work with the newer update to Firebase Android SDK

Here is the scenario to solve your problem:

1. In your callback of token refresh first check if the `FirebaseUser`
   authentication is present. If present simply write the token to your
   Firebase database. Also store a boolean to Shared Preferences to
   true if token saved in db else set it to false. This solves the
   issue that you don't have database access but you are getting token.
2. Next create a Async task in separate class which simply call
       `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` to trigger the
       `onTokenRefresh` in service.
3. Next in your login process after firebase auth success call the
       above async task which will force the `onTokenRefresh` callback. Now
       since user auth is present your write to db will be successful (also
       setting the shared pref *token_sent_to_db* = true).
4. Now in you launching activity where you are checking user auth for
       navigation to appropriate activity add a check if the shared pref 
       *token_sent_to_db* = false; call the Async Task again. This will ensure that if some how above steps miss the token save in db we can
       send the token again.
5. Lastly the token for FCM will not change until you force it to
       change or if the apps gets un-installed. So the token will only get
       written to db once only.

P.S: Also make sure that after user logout you expire the FCM token otherwise your server will keep sending the notification to the logged out user. *FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();*