# What method should I use now since FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to know what would be the correct way to get Firebase token for sending push notification now that getToken() is deprecated.

Comment: Simple https://stackoverflow.com/a/52120871/6891563

Comment: quickly access using FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();

Answer (score 236):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

FirebaseInstanceId is deprecated but now you can use **FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token**.

For example:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        if(result != null){
            fbToken = result
            // DO your thing with your firebase token
        }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

As [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken()) says :

> **This method was deprecated**.
> In favour of getInstanceId().

[getInstanceId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getInstanceId()) will return a Task with and InstanceIdResult. Like this:

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {                    
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                      String deviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                      // Do whatever you want with your token now
                      // i.e. store it on SharedPreferences or DB
                      // or directly send it to server 
                }
});
```

Though is true that this approach will literally replace the use of **FirebaseInstanceId.getInstanceId().getToken()**, it does not solve the fact that **FirebaseInstanceIdService** is also deprecated leaving us with another question that is: where to use it?
It can be used in any Activity context that it will always return the token. But what if we want to get the token only on creation and when it is rarely updated?
For that you should override new method **onNewToken** from our old **FirebaseMessagingService** implementation:
(Yes, "Messaging", not "InstanceId")

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    String deviceToken = s;
    // Do whatever you want with your token now
    // i.e. store it on SharedPreferences or DB
    // or directly send it to server 
}
```

This way code will remain leaner and wont even be necessary to use the first approach.

Comment: I am using this in fragment and it is showing -Non-static method 'getInstanceId()' cannot be referenced from a static contex -How to solve it

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've edited the answer to call getInstance also as getInstanceId is an instance method.

Comment: @jantoo did you tried the edited answer?

Comment: @BhaskarJyotiDutta You did it!. Also please approve the edit I've suggested to use the correct way and grammar  to ask in Stack Overflow

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. I am I not good at English? (Sorry, if I have done some mistake)

Comment: The onSuccess callback enter only once, the first time.
If you want to get the Token that the app have already registered in a second time? I try to find out a way to require it without storing in app preferences

Comment: @phemt.latd I did not understand your question.

Comment: @Facundo sorry, if you use the new async listener to get the token, the first time the application get it, the next time the app not fire the callback beacuse the token is already generated.
There is a method to get the already generated token or you must save it in SharedPreferences when the success callback is fired?

Comment: @phemt.latd this code always returns the token, not only the first time. It will be executed only when token is updated if you put this code inside method onTokenRefresh. if you want to retrieve the token every time the app starts you can include this code on your MainActivity.onCreate method.

Comment: Why passing `context` when actually it can be done without?!!

Comment: @HamzehSoboh I've edited as in the case of InstanceIdResult it may not be necessary,  but to answer to your question take a look at this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#activity-scoped_listeners) about [activity scoped listeners](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#activity-scoped_listeners).

Comment: @Facundo, before onNewToken was introduced, onTokenRefresh was supposed to call whenever system invalidate the tokens. Is this behavior same for onNewToken ? Will onNewToken be called when my existing tokens need to be refreshed or when system will invalid ny existing tokens ?

Comment: @HeyYou good question. I didn't found any documentation specifying this behavior. Gonna dive a little bit more on this matter.

Comment: @Facundo Documentation says "Called when a new token for the default Firebase project is generated.This is invoked after app install when a token is first generated, and again if the token changes." Intresting part is "again if token changes" does it means it will also be called when system determine that token need to be refresh ?

Comment: @HeyYou sure, it is called every time token is refreshed.

Comment: This is not a solution when you need the token outside a callback. This is not functional.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim I agree. newToken doesn't seem to get called 100% so another method to retrieve the existing token is required

Comment: @behelit My solution was to keep trying to get it until the system returns a valid value (aka recursive).

Comment: Is there any problem if I add FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(...) in Activity launcher onCreate() so It will be called all the time user opens my app?

Comment: @CarlosEduardoKiLee it shouldn't be any problem. It may not be a best practice as it will return the same value until the token is refreshed.

Comment: this deprecated again

Comment: FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true) 
DOES NOT GIVE MESSAGING TOKEN, IT CHANGES AFTER EVERY LAUNCH

Comment: The token received from `FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken()` and `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()` is different

Comment: @SrikarReddy FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() returns the token as same format as onNewToken method and this token worked for me.

Comment: @SaeidMohammadi I have a custom `FirebaseApp` instance. I can't configure it using `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()`. This just gives the token for the default `FirebaseApp`.

Comment: @SrikarReddy you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68917974/5735993

Comment: @SaeidMohammadi That is same as what you said above. How does `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()` know that it has to take a custom instance. You can't pass anything to `getInstance()`.

Comment: @SaeidMohammadi Looking for an alternate to this method https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp)
`public static FirebaseInstanceId getInstance (FirebaseApp app)`

Answer (score 37):

FirebaseInstanceIdService was deprecated .!

just override  `onNewToken()` in `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class LatestFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String mToken) {
    super.onNewToken(mToken);
    Log.e("TOKEN",mToken);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
}}
```

In`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service
        android:name=".LatestFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

`getToken()` This is also deprecated.!

if you need to get token in your activity use the below code.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String mToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
           Log.e("Token",mToken);
     }
 });
```

Comment: And now FirebaseInstanceId is deprecated, yay

Comment: Have you found any solution @mliu?

Comment: FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() is the new way.... source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token

Comment: thus, that's deprecated..

Comment: note: if you don't receive onNewToken as often as you might think, it's troublesome if you have mutli-user support