# Build error while syncing 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.2'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I am adding firebase analytics for crash report. while sycnchronizing im am getting below error

```
ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an 
exact version (e.g. "[17.1.1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the 
library will be unknown. Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0 -> 
com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[17.1.1], but firebase-iid version was 20.0.2.The following 
dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to 
the artifact with the issue.

-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@16.4.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.5.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.2
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{strictly 17.5.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@{strictly 16.4.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@{strictly 20.0.2}       
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@{strictly 17.2.2}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 17.2.2}
```

Comment: Make sure your dependencies are all up to date with each other. A lot of what you're using is rather old. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: when i add latest version of all the firebase dependencies then FirebaseInstanceIdService error is coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update all your firebase dependencies to the latest version. Also after you update, you need to update to androidx and use `compileSdkVersion` 28.

Also related to `firebaseinstanceid`, you need check the following:

[What to use now that FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125169/what-to-use-now-that-firebaseinstanceid-getinstance-gettoken-is-deprecated)