# Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID different in build APK and Signed APK why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, uniqueidentifier, deviceid

```
String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                     Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I'm using this to take android id. Doubt is ANDROID_ID how could be different for signed apk and build apk of same device?
I need unique identity of my device. If ANDROID_ID is changed then is it good to use this?

Answer (score 2):

Android 8.0+ [randomizes the `ANDROID_ID` value](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#privacy-all):

> For apps installed on a device running Android 8.0, the value of ANDROID_ID is now scoped per app signing key, as well as per user. The value of ANDROID_ID is unique for each combination of app-signing key, user, and device. As a result, apps with different signing keys running on the same device no longer see the same Android ID (even for the same user).

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) has an extensive guide on unique identifiers. Also, be sure to discuss your plans with an attorney.

Comment: Hello Sir , Is there not any other way to get the Device ID which become unique for the application , please help me on it.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: That would appear to be covered in [the documentation that I linked to in the answer](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids).

Comment: Means i need to use the **READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE** permission to get the device id which become same for all applications. @CommonsWare Sir

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: I do not believe that you need that permission for the Advertising ID or Instance ID mentioned [in the first section of the documentation that I linked to in the answer](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#best-practices-android-identifiers).

Comment: For the Advertising ID i need to implement the AD-MOB and for Instance ID which thing i need to implement, any example please @CommonsWare sir

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125384/115145

Comment: Thanks Sir but it may vary from application to application.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: Well, yes. Your original comment asked for an identifier "which become unique for the application".

Comment: Sir , Last question, Its not possible to get unique id which become same for all the applications ?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha: I hope that is no longer possible, for privacy reasons.