# Unresolved reference: FirebaseInstanceId

Tags: android, firebase

I encountered such an error this morning.

Is this method no longer used?

> ../android/screens/MainActivity.kt: (25, 32): Unresolved reference: FirebaseInstanceId

```
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId
```

> .../android/screens/MainActivity.kt: (201, 9): Unresolved reference: FirebaseInstanceId

```
   private fun getFCMToken() {
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener {
        val token = it.token
        presenter.sendFCMToken(token)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125169/what-to-use-now-that-firebaseinstanceid-getinstance-gettoken-is-deprecated ?

Comment: Have you added the corresponding dependencies?

Comment: yes i added them all

Answer (score 7):

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    if (task.result != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(task.result)) {
                        val token: String = task.result!!
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now You can use this for get Token

Comment: Do I need to install any package for this?