# Using FirebaseInstallations and FirebaseMessaging instead of FirebaseInstanceId

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating to my project a piece of code that is using the deprecated interface `FirebaseInstanceId` instead of `FirebaseMessaging` and `FirebaseInstallations` to register and receive incoming calls.

As I am new to Firebase, I don't fully understand the original code and I'm unsure how to change it in order to achieve the desired outcome.

I wasn't able to fully improve my understanding and find a solution when looking at these posts:

- [FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated)
- [What method should I use now since FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125169/what-method-should-i-use-now-since-firebaseinstanceid-getinstance-gettoken-i)

Looking at the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#getInstanceId()), my basic understanding is that:

1. `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()` *we are returning an instance of the class*
2. `.getInstanceId()` *to then returns a Task*
3. `.addOnSuccessListener(this, instance -> ...)` *that then calls a method if it is succesful*
4. `fcmToken = instanceIdResult.getToken()` *which gets a FCM Token*

However, I'm not exactly sure if this is correct nor am I clear on what exactly the instanceIdResult and Task represent here.

**Code**

```
/* Register your FCM token to receive incoming call invites */
private void registerForCallInvites() {
   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(this, instanceIdResult -> {
            String fcmToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            Log.i(TAG, "Registering with FCM");
            Voice.register(accessToken, Voice.RegistrationChannel.FCM, fcmToken, registrationListener);
        });
}
```

How does this code actually work and how would I go about rewriting it to make it compile?

Comment: You can learn about Task using its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks).

Answer (score -1):

Referred to the deprecated FirebaseInstanceId, use FirebaseMessaging:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token -> (string)FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken()
```

Please refer to this link:
https://gist.github.com/jfversluis/dd760594099066c7450d50cce6499368?permalink_comment_id=4485646#gistcomment-4485646