# FCM Push Notification not working when app close in some of the devices like xiaomi oppo, vivo,Redmi and some of OS (Oxygen OS, Color OS, MIUI etc)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM Push Notification not working when app close in some of the devices like xiaomi, oppo, vivo,Redmi and some of OS (Oxygen OS, Color OS, MIUI etc).

But other devices and OS working good.

Does anyone have experience about it?

**Android end code.**

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());


}
```

}

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

```
private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {


}
```

}

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**Sever End Code**

```
{
"notification": {
"title": "FCM Kazi",
"body": "FCM bdoy1 ",
"sound": "default",
"click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
"icon": "fcm_push_icon"
},
"data": {
"param1": "value1",
"param2": "value2"
},
"to": "cVL4I6upF-g:APA91bE7EFv3apIMHuEL_oCoVvhhrUw-ftM6S11RE9HOF58wf3ewYkDUh9wUhUCMIa6zoftOgGH5HWt0rPKVHw2OShn06tIESFnGo9u8rooJ9qfiXQQlg-zZzjgi0cQ64BUaZnUCM09R",
"priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: Check this answer it will work  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated/51129304#51129304

Comment: I read a much and when i removed "notification" block, it worked in background and foreground properly. But you need to add "title" and "body" to "data" block. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/6055194 https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795553/6055194

Comment: Thanks @ZhebzhikBabich but not working some of the devices like xiaomi oppo, vivo,Redmi and some of OS (Oxygen OS, Color OS, MIUI etc). this problme only  Color OS,

Comment: Did you try to change yout version of firebase messaging to 17.3.x (1,2,3) and remove FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: Yes. @ZhebzhikBabich
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

Comment: That's really serious bug. Minus to Google

Comment: i am checked redmi is working fine. are u give correct to-address id(token) otherwise use firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fcmsample-a38c3/notification/compose.  choose  new message and select usersegment  and app package select as send message it received  install all devices

Comment: @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri

{
    "multicast_id": 6495072320217040420,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1539170495316171%c6c2f7c7c6c2f7c7"
        }
    ]
}

FCM Return  "success": 1, It working when FCM are working on foreground and background but not kill status.

Comment: @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri, 
I am testing on oppo android 6 colorOS.

Answer (score -1):

Use only data playload and remove notification playload. Data playload always receive wheather app is open or close doesn't matter. Notification playload works only if app is in forground. And if you are not receiving on few devices go to device settings and enable receive notification for that app. Few manufacturer doesn't allow notification by default.