# Unable to get call back in firebase FirebaseInstanceIdService to get token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

this is my class to get Token:->

```
  public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
            private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();
            @Override
            public void onTokenRefresh() {
                super.onTokenRefresh();
                String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        }
      }
```

this is my manifest file :->

```
 <service
            android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

i have written this code to get device token but i am not getting call back in this class so that i can get device token can you please tell me where i am doing wrong i have given internet permission also i have puted google.json file in app folder can any one please suggest or help me in this issue .

Comment: [`MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129304/7666442)

Comment: then what i have to use can you please suggest me  @NileshRathod

Comment: I have already added link in above comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129304/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod firebase which version we have to use for this ?

Comment: latest `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated)