# Firebase Remote config: FirebaseInstanceId null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Hi I am trying to use remote config in Firebase on Android, but am having problems getting it working. I am using the following versions:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.3
```

However, it is crashing when I try and fetch the remote config with the error:

```
   FirebaseRemoteConfig: IPC failure: 10:NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getId()' on a null object reference
```

I presume this means that the FirebaseInstanceId is null. I am initialising Firebase using:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)
```

This had been working previously using 11.8.0, but not even that version works now. I think something else has changed somewhere else to cause this, but I have run out of ideas as to what it could be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated

Comment: Firebase instance is fetched based on the information in the json file. Check google's json file once, if any changes in keystore or project info?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Is this really the solution. Does remote config have a dependency on messaging?

Comment: @Charan The json file had not changed.