# FCM token contains double quotations

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ii have configured android for FCM.

```
public class DERFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    }
}
```

The token that I get from firebase server is following

```
"c5pu6rD06ts:APA91bHEgXUbJR8UegRPnLMgowEC6QxUPP73TiSBIHG1Pe0I8u22298rjpbXBsK94ExTmTbL0VT009AhsIqgMSkoLFZJDuaPSpaLlqBAyIrrtzsdLuWhvCp6CtkZwMT88P-WxBFCT2DH"
```

This token contains double quotations. So what I am doing wrong that server send me this token. Can any one help me..?

Due to this , when server send request to this token I am getting following error

> "message": "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration
>   token",
>           "domain": "global",
>           "reason": "badRequest"

Comment: [`FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129304/7666442)

Comment: You are probably copying pasting the token from the console with the enclosing quotes that are merely used to display it.

Comment: quotes are just to represent that its of type 'String'.

Comment: As @user2297550 noted, you are possibly copying the string from the **debug console** which you captured using breakpoints. Try `Log` class to log the fcm, and see what's the output.