# Facing Some problem with Firebase InstanceId

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing some errors in an apk build. Here is my code.

```
package com.my.mybooks.services;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;



/**
 * FirebaseInstanceIdService Gets FCM instance ID token from Firebase Cloud Messaging Server
 */

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    //*********** Called whenever the Token is Generated or Refreshed ********//

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.i("My_Shop", "refreshedFCMToken= " + refreshedToken);
    }

}
```

> error: cannot find symbol import
>   com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
>                                 ^   symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceIdService   location: package com.google.firebase.iid

My AndroidManifest.xml is

```
  <service android:name="com.atmajaa.atmajaabooks.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.atmajaa.atmajaabooks.services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated ages ago. It is replaced with `FirebaseMessagingService`. You're facing that error because latest Firebase libraries don't contain that class anymore.

As the documentation of FirebaseInstanceIdService [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService) states,

> This class is deprecated. In favour of overriding onNewToken in
>   FirebaseMessagingService. Once that has been implemented, this service
>   can be safely removed.

You can find how to migrate to `FirebaseMessagingService` below

[FirebaseInstanceIdService is Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated).

Comment: Thanks! Now I have one more question: In my AndroidManifest.xml file I am using this code, what need to change here:

Comment: <service android:name="com.atmajaa.atmajaabooks.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.atmajaa.atmajaabooks.services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

Comment: It's very hard to understand anything here. If you have any error, maybe try googling? Because I won't be of any help in comments section

Comment: I just edited my question. Added the AndroidManifest.xml part

Comment: You'll get complete info on migrating to FirebaseMessagingService on the link that I added in my answer, and you can always accept the answer if it helped you