# Ionic cordova build issue after plugin firebasex is added

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic, Angular web app in typescript. Build errors are showing when `cordova-plugin-firebasex` is added.

Package.json

```
"@capacitor/core": "2.2.1",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.29.0",

"cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.4.0",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
"cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^11.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
```

tsconfig.json

```
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
],
"resolveJsonModule": true
```

Error message:

```
Updating resource files at platforms/android
Prepared android project successfully
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter/apply.js
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 48 source files in 722ms
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-androidx for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-androidx/scripts/apply-to-gradle.properties.js
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/scripts/copy_google_service_files.js
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-firebasex for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-    plugin-firebasex/scripts/after_prepare.js
cordova-plugin-firebasex: Preparing Firebase on Android
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/devsec/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/devsec/Android/Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Gradle Distribution URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

> Task :app:processDebugManifest
/home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-34:50 Warning:
        activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was     tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:27 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:913: error: cannot find symbol
                    settings.put("developerModeEnabled",     remoteConfigInfo.getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled());
                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   method isDeveloperModeEnabled()
  location: class FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/file/AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 11s
23 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 18 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/build.gradle
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: /home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/build.gradle
    at makeError (/home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (/home/devsec/code/sources/alum/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/execa/index.js:114:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    
        cordova build android --debug --verbose exited with exit code 1.
    
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +0ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +14ms
```

Anybody familiar with this?
I was trying to set up FCM, push notifications using Angular, Firebase, Ionic. Whenever I have added `cordovo-plugin-firebasex`, then this build error is raised.

I can see that there is some kind of deprecated function is being used somewhere. But how to suppress the error, or fix it, from ionic / cordova?

Comment: Try removing platform and then add. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebasex

Comment: Tried that multiple times, I've tried changing the plugin too, `cordova-plugin-firebase` turned out to be outdated.

Comment: do I really need `cordova-plugin-firebasex` for push notifications? Could it be done without this plugin?

Comment: Yes that's only currently latest and working plugin. Try updating SDK and plugins of Android studio.

Comment: Have you tried the `cordova-plugin-firebasex@11.0.3-cli` version?

Comment: You Can use this Plugin for Push Notifications: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm

Comment: Here is the Example How you Can use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63561228/5909026

Comment: Thank you guys... I'm making progress on solving my issues. Thank you for the help and guidance. Very much appreciate it. I'll update the question, if I'm hitting a dead end.