# Ionic Firebase: fcm.getToken Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getToken')

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing firebase on an application using Ionic Angular (cordova). When the Application is launched it does not go past the SplashScreen and the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getToken')

is displayed on the console. Sometimes, If I close and re-launch the app loads and the firebase token is generated. Other times it remains stuck on the splashscreen.

A previous question recommended changing the FCM provider to
`{ provide: FCM, useValue: { getToken: () => Promise.resolve(true) } }`

But when I do that other FCM functions stop working. For example, I get:

`this.fcm.onNotification() is not a function`

This is the code block

```
    this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
  console.log(token);
});
```

I was able to resolve the problem using

```
import { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx';
```

constructor(private fcm: FCM){}

private async pushSetup() {
await this.platform.ready();

```
console.log('FCM SETUP INIT');
if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  return;
}

console.log('IN CORDOVA');

this.hasPermission = await this.fcm.requestPushPermission();
console.log('CHECK hasPermission:', this.hasPermission);

this.token = await this.fcm.getToken();
console.log('CHECK getToken: ' + this.token);

console.log('ON NOTIFICATION SUBSCRIBE');
this.fcm
  .onTokenRefresh()
  .subscribe((newToken) => console.log('NEW TOKEN:', newToken));
this.fcm
  .onNotification()
  .subscribe((payload: object) => console.log('ON NOTIFICATION:', payload));
```

}

From [I'm unable to get Device token in an ionic app as a result of Cannot read property 'onTokenRefresh' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553206/im-unable-to-get-device-token-in-an-ionic-app-as-a-result-of-cannot-read-proper?rq=2)