# What does onTokenRefresh deprecation mean?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to setup Firebase Cloud Messaging for the first time. In the guide for Web app, there is a section on monitoring registration token refresh with `onTokenRefresh`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?authuser=0#access_the_registration_token

However, looking in reference documentation I see this method is deprecated.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging?authuser=0#ontokenrefresh

[image]

What does it mean there is no need to handle token rotation? Is a token obtained with `getToken` permanent? It's not a standard JWT token, so I couldn't decrypt if there is some sort of expiration.

Comment: If you find the documentation confusing, I suggest using the "send feedback" button at the top docs pages to send a note to the team. Indeed, the deprecation notice doesn't seem to make sense, and I personally would expect to have to use onTokenRefresh to get device tokens that do actually change over time.

Comment: Appreciate your comment. I did send feedback, but I don't suppose I will get my answer there. I guess I will keep using onTokenRefresh and hopefully, it won't just disappear one day.

Comment: You need to use `onNewToken()` now Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated

Comment: @DVSingh Well, that's for Android, but I don't see any mention of such a method for JavaScript SDK. It certainly doesn't seem like a good idea to use undocumented methods.