# Web api key is not generated in firebase while creating a new project as stated on the documentation

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

On the Firebase documentation, it states that the web API key will be auto-generated when:

> Firebase will automatically create a new web API key for your project when you do
> any of the following:
>
> - Create a Firebase project > Browser key auto-created.
> - Create a Firebase> iOS App > iOS key auto-created.
> - Create a Firebase Android App > Android > key auto-created.

I have tried creating a new Firebase project as stated, but the web API key is not being generated.

[image: Image file showing error]

**UPDATE:** The answer to the question is in the comments.  ("It gets generated once you go into the "Authentication" section for the first time")

Comment: You have to create Authentication in your Firebase project. Check your "Authentication" section!

Comment: It gets generated once you go into the  "Authentication" section for the first time

Comment: I contacted Firebase support and got an answer. The web key is also known as the *Browser key* in Google Cloud: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: in your firebase panel just open authentication section and it then return to the last page. API key will be there :)

Comment: Thanks Guys, it does create after you enable authentication.