# What is difference between WebAPI Key & Server API key in FCM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I notice that in my firebase console it says web API key was not generated initially. I followed this thread [web-api-key-is-not-generated-in-firebase-while-creating-a-new-project-as-stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64690983/web-api-key-is-not-generated-in-firebase-while-creating-a-new-project-as-stated) and it generated a new web api key.

[WebAPI Key in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdaRx.png)

I also saw that there is a server api key for legacy which I am currently using. I read [concept-options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) and it says server key is only for server-to-server communication.

[Server API Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv0m5.png)

So does this mean the client side of the code requires the web-api key to generate FCM registration tokens?

Pls help me understand what web api key is used for , am i correct to say that fcm tokens should be generated using web api key as one of the parameters & server key is used only to authorize the server side fcm requests.

Also in the context of HTTP V1, will web api key continue to work for generating FCM tokens?