# Push notification not working with FCM after changing "google-service.json" file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

Recently I changed the “google-services.json” file in my app. The previous developer use different “google-services.json” file, so I changed it for getting firebase analytics. I don’t have the access the previous Firebase project, so I cannot use firebase analytics.
After changing the “google-services.json” file, I am not getting push notification in my app. Do I have to change anything from backend?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any other error message?

Comment: No error message, but onMessageReceived isn't getting called. 
I talked with backend developer, they are saying they are identifying my device. But they didn't update server key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Backend is still sending the push messages to the previous FireBase project. So when you change the FireBase project and have a new `google-services.json` configuration you need to update the `ServerKey` on your backend as well.

**How to get the Server Key on Firebase**

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Select the project
3. Click on the Project Overview → Project Settings
4. Select "Cloud Messaging" tab.
5. Under "Project credentials" you should be able to see the Server key or generate a new one.

Comment: I talked with backend developer, they are saying they are identifying my device without updating server key. But I am not getting push notification. Any idea?

Comment: Here are some more documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337512/where-can-i-find-the-api-key-for-firebase-cloud-messaging/ and https://blog.techmagic.co/firebase-cloud-messaging-for-push-notifications/

Comment: Thank you so much for you help

Answer (score 0):

Just changing “google-service.json” file won't work

After changing the “google-service.json”, run `flutter clean` will fix the issue